# Why is wrong redirecting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, model-view-controller

Have model with tasks they are done and todo. In view have link and when click the link it must change task from todo to done. It's my routes

```
get 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#change_to_done', as: 'change_to_done'
```

my view

```
<% unless task.done %>
        <td><%= check_box_tag "cb_tasks[]", task.id %></td>
        <td><%= link_to task.title, task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Done', change_to_done_path(task.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
      <% end %>
```

and my controller

```
  def change_to_done
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.done = true
    @task.save
  end
```

when clicking the link redirecting to the show path

```
Started GET "/tasks/32" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-26 11:59:06 +0200
Processing by TasksController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"32"}
  Task Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks" WHERE "tasks"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 32], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering tasks/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered tasks/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 55.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

What's wrong? I need only to change field state from false to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a `resources :tasks` above a get `'task/:id'` the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line.

Try to change the endpoint, for example:

```
get 'change_to_done/:id', to: 'tasks#change_to_done', as: 'change_to_done'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have `resources :tasks` in your routes file. Rails resolves this, and ignore `get 'tasks/:id', to: 'tasks#change_to_done', as: 'change_to_done'` this route. You should specify the exact action `get 'tasks/:id/change_to_done', to: 'tasks#change_to_done', as: 'change_to_done'`